# TFS 2015 -> 2017 Update1 Projects Not Showing In Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, team-foundation-server

So after an update to TFS 2017 with Update1 from TFS 2013 All Project Collection Administrators can view/checkout/commit to any project in that collection using the Web UI.

When any member of the Project Collection Administrators goes to pull a project using Visual Studio 2015 or 2017 they can only see the Projects that they have created themselves.

Ideally we can easily allow for all users in a group to be able to see all projects in a project collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to Microsoft when upgrading from 2013 -> 2017 it is important to go straight to Update 1.

I was under the impression that based on previous info found that you have to step through the updates. but the bug it not corrected with the update 1 install after 2017 is installed